# Go gonum plot, storing png data to Database

Tags: sqlite, go, plot, writer, reader

I am generating some Histograms from the gonum/plot library in Go. Normally you would save the image, as .png for instance like this:

```
if err := plot.Save(2.5*vg.Inch, 2.5*vg.Inch, "my_histo.png"); err != nil {
    log.Println("[!] error creating plot", err)
}
```

And this generates all the .png at the folder. No issue with that.

I want to use this plots on a GUI(Python tk) and basically I want to store them in an SQLITE database, with a text key that corresponds to the physical object, which this histogram data was generated from, in order to access them from Python. On the GUI, there is a dictionary and you choose which histogram data you wish to display, and this is synced from the database.

I want to save this png Histogram at a column in my Database that it is Blob type and then I want to extract it from there, when needed.

Now, I know that this might not be the best way to implement this, but I would like to understand how Reader/Writer works, so I would like to know if I can do what I describe and if yes, how?

For example, I can generate those png histograms on a folder and then save the location that they were saved as a text at the database, instead of sending larger amount of bytes, but I was wondering if I can avoid saving the png and save it directly at the database, as a []bytes possible?

To that extend, I noticed that my plot object has the attribute WriterTo and I can do something like this:

```
n, err := plot.WriterTo(2.5*vg.Inch, 2.5*vg.Inch, "png")
```

This returns the number of bytes written, and if there was an error. So, what is this actually useful for?
How do I access my data/png, after using this WriterTo method?

Comment: You're not using an io.Reader or io.Writer at all. But to learn about those, you should go through [A tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org), particularly the section on [Readers](https://tour.golang.org/methods/21).

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks a lot. So, would you say that what I described, is possible to do it by using io.Writers?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Look closely at the return types of the WriterTo method. Interestingly, the [Save](https://github.com/gonum/plot/blob/master/plot.go#L455) method uses WriterTo itself.

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot! I checked the save method too. I think that being new to GO, I find Read/Write interfaces a bit complicated to understand, but I will get there I hope. Thanks